# how to create group of elements using svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I have been trying to create a group of elements created by sag.js with the help of group() but failed.
I would be grateful if anyone find me the way of getting out of this. Thanks in advance.
Here is my try:

```
  const width = 525; //889.37;//510
  const height = 675; //690.44;//660

  //let svg = document.getElementById("create");
  //var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  //let group = document.createElementNS(ns, "g");
  //group.setAttribute("name", "mygroup")

  for (let i = 0; i <= height; i = i + 15) {
     for (let j = 0; j <= width; j = j + 15) {

        //var group = draw.group();

        //var group = SVG().group();
        //var group = draw.group();
        //group.path('M10,20L30,40');
        var rect = SVG('#svg').rect(i, j, 15, 15);
        //group.add(rect);
        rect.attr({
           fill: "#ed2e3b",
           "fill-opacity": 0.001,
           stroke: "#000"
        });


        //group.appendChild(rect);

     }
     //group.appendChild(rect);
  }
  //group.appendChild(rect);
  //svg.appendChild(group);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seams to work. For each *i* there is a new group.

```js
const width = 525; //889.37;//510
const height = 675; //690.44;//660

var draw = SVG().addTo('body').size(width, height);

for (let i = 0; i <= height; i = i + 15) {
  var group = draw.group();
  for (let j = 0; j <= width; j = j + 15) {

    var rect = draw.rect(i, j, 15, 15);

    rect.attr({
      fill: "#ed2e3b",
      "fill-opacity": 0.001,
      stroke: "#000"
    });
    group.add(rect);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.1.1/svg.min.js"></script>
```